# SQL Query Aging Report

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, left-join, datediff

I have created a SQL query that is supposed to generate an Aging Report (show outstanding balances and classifies in what aging bucket they should be placed in, based on the number of days unpaid).  The query is below:

```
SELECT (case when a.DaysOutstanding between 0 and 15 then 'AR_15'
             when a.DaysOutstanding between 16 and 30 then 'AR_15'
             when a.DaysOutstanding between 31 and 60 then 'AR_60'
             else 'AR_61'
        end)
FROM (SELECT RECEIPTS.CUST_No, sum(SALES.INV_AMT - RECEIPT.REC_AMT) as bal
      FROM RECEIPTS, SALES
      GROUP BY RECEIPTS.CUST_No
      ) b left outer join
     (SELECT RECEIPTS.CUST_No, MAX(RECEIPTS.REC_DATE) as LastPayDate,
      datediff(d, SALES.INV_DATE, getdate()) as DaysOutstanding
      FROM RECEIPTS, SALES
      GROUP BY RECEIPTS.CUST_No
      ) a on b.CUST_No = b.CUST_No
GROUP BY (case when a.DaysOutstanding between 0 and 15 then 'AR_15'
             when a.DaysOutstanding between 16 and 30 then 'AR_15'
             when a.DaysOutstanding between 31 and 60 then 'AR_60'
             else 'AR_61'
          end)
HAVING sum(SALES.INV_AMT - RECEIPT.REC_AMT) > 0
```

The query should filter out the invoices that have been paid off in full (=0).  I believe that there is an error with something in the HAVING clause as well as the datediff line of code.

Is there something wrong or something missing that I can use to properly create the query?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read about [mcve]s and act on it.

Comment: Shouldn't some of those `'AR_15'`s be `'AR_30'`s?